# Trying to run SQL agent job from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2012, jobs, sql-agent-job

I have a stored procedure that has an "execute as" with a service account
that stored proc calls  sp_start_job with the name of the agent job to start.

I have given the service account membership to SQLAgentOperatorRole, SQLAgentReaderRole, SQLAgentUserRole, TargetServerRole and db_sisoperator.
I gave TargetServerRole  permission to execute the sp_start_job and sp_stop_job

But still get "Permission denied on the object 'sp_start_job'.
If i alter database chaning on the client database the error changes to "permission denied on "xp_sqlagent_is_starting". I don't think this is the right direction and was wondering if there is anything else i can do to track down this issue.

Comment: Did you consider Permissions on Msdb Database?

Comment: in the end i gave it sysadmin access to the server.  This didn't remove the error. Eventually i dropped the execute as and ran it under my own credentials ...no problem.  No idea why that account has such issues even with sysadmin access.

Comment: VtC here and punt it over to dba.stackexchange.com This seems more suited to their userbase